# Can't upgrade from Xcode 4.2 to 4.2.1

Tags: xcode, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from Xcode 4.2 (4D199) to Xcode 4.2.1 (4D502).
On AppStore, when I try to install the new version, it says I already have Xcode installed and  I have to use Software Update instead.
When I run Software Update, it says all applications are up to date.

Any clues?

Thanks,

Ecil

Comment: This isn't programming related. Better try asking on the Apple developer forum.

Comment: I deleted "Install Xcode.app" from Applications folder and then it solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @DarkDust Stackoverflow is not only for programming, it's also for "software tools commonly used by programmers" http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: @gcamp: While that's true and useful e.g. to cover topics like _How do I this with SubVersion_ I doubt that it's useful to a larger audience that there's an issue with updating to a dot release of an IDE. So the close reason _too localized_ would fit here as well.

Comment: I also am having this problem.  It is really frustrating that this question - which is very much on-top for stackoverflow - has been closed!

Answer (score 4):

Use the App Store under the Apple menu. Enter "Xcode" in the search field. Click "INSTALL" under the Xcode icon.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall xcode completely (delete all folders having anything to do with it besides the projects you want to keep) then re install.